# Basic HTML to open link in sidebar

Tags: html, firefox, sidebar

I'm trying to use basic HTML to load a page in a Firefox (v22, I know it's outdated but it's what I'm forced to use) sidebar instead of a new tab or window. I have the HTML all set to automatically redirect to my desired URL after a short time, but once it loads it's loading in the main window and not the sidebar like I want. I tried the basic 'target=_' options and none of those worked. Is there a simple way to accomplish my goal? I feel like an idiot but I'd rather feel stupid and ask for help and get an answer than continue beating my head against a wall. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `frames` for this

The `<frameset>` element holds one or more `<frame>` elements. Each  element can hold a separate document.

Like,

```
<frameset cols="20%,*"> 
     <frame name="left" src="col1.html"> 
     <frame name="right" src="col2.html">
</frameset>
```

See examples here

**[DEMOS >>](http://www.quackit.com/html/examples/frames/)**

**[EXAMPLE 1>>](http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_3.html)**

Comment: Beautiful, that'll work nicely. If I wanted to link text to open in a sidebar without the use of frames though (similar to the way a href="url" target="_blank" would open it in a new tab), is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why cant you use pure AJAX or jquery-AJAX API to do that. So that you can load some other pages to anywhere in your page even without a page reload